# variable attributes changes between GCC versions - "nobits"

Tags: gcc, memory-management, linker, arm, embedded

I was using an older version of GCC (version 6.3.0) for my project - arm processor.
I then moved to a newer version (version 10.2.1 20201103) - arm processor.

when I wanted that a specific section will only be a "space holder", for working memory, for example, I used an attribute

```
__attribute__((section(".sctionName,\"aw\",@nobits#")))
```

when using the new GCC version I get an error:

```
Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `,'
```

is there an option to do this in the new GCC version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The section attribute syntax has not changed between [gcc 6](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.5.0/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html#Common-Variable-Attributes) and [gcc 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html#Common-Variable-Attributes).  The parameter for `section` is just the section name; the `,\"aw\",@nobits#` part appears to be a "dirty-trick" (according to [What does the "aw" flag in the section attribute mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252812/what-does-the-aw-flag-in-the-section-attribute-mean)) to inject qualifiers into the generated assembler code.  However gcc 10 is clearly checking for valid section names where gcc 6 allowed any old text and simply inserted it into the code.

You perhaps need a more "official" means of defining the behaviour of the section.  Through the linker script perhaps?

Comment: thanks, another follow up question, is there a way to make a section to be a placeholder? I want the section to exist only on the "runtime" but not to take place in the image itself.

Comment: @Itay I am sure there is, but you should post a new question.  SO is not a discussion forum.  Besides toy will get a larger audience for a question that a comment - more than just me!